# Flink Exponential Backoff On Just One Task

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Flink app with multiple tasks. In the event that one of those tasks has an error during processing, I'd like to do an exponential backoff on that one task without restarting the whole job. When using Kafka directly rather than through Flink, I can pause the consumer and then resume it later after a certain amount of time has passed. Is it possible to pause a Flink data source or task? Is there another way to accomplish an exponential backoff on just one task while not affecting the other tasks?

Answer (score 0):

In general Flink itself does not offer such capability. Now, it may be possible to mimic such capability in some operators like specific sinks or AsyncIO. For Kafka, for example You may setup producer in a way that it will retry failed messages and wait given amount of time before any subsequent retry. This isn't exactly exponential backoff, but as close as You can get without writing own sink.

So, it generally depends on the place You want to achieve that, it may be possible to have backoff that is not exponential out-of-the-box. As a last resort, You may try to simply write Your own sink that implements exponential backoff.